# Robust way to get the user home directory?

Tags: bash, unix

`$HOME` can be unset. Therefore tilde `~` is the solution.
(source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Here are my two solutions

`HOME="$(cd ~ && pwd)"`

and

`HOME="$(cd ~ && ${PWD})"`

Which should I use? `pwd` or `${PWD}`? Or do you have an other/better solution?

Comment: Why not just `HOME=~`?

Comment: Are you aware that `HOME` can be modified, and that `~` will reflect that? That could be good or bad depending on what you mean by "bulletproof".

Comment: @wjandrea what if ```~``` contains whitespaces? If a path contain whitespace you should use quotation marks: ```VAR="path"``` and then for example ```cd "${VAR}"``` otherwise you have a problem

Comment: ```HOME="$(echo ~)"```

Comment: `HOME=$(POSIXLY_CORRECT=1; PATH=/bin:/usr/bin; \unset -f command; command /bin/rbash -c 'IFS=: read -ra h <<<$(getent passwd $(whoami)); echo "${h[5}"')`

Comment: @jhnc why the ```/bin/rbash -c```?

Comment: @user19264607 eg. `read(){ h[5]=/fakehome; }`. I didn't want to write `command ...`  / `builtin ...` everywhere. Still not "bulletproof". eg. Doesn't protect against `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: @user19264607 An expansion in the RHS of an assignment is not word-split or globbed. Try it yourself: `HOME='/some nonexistent path'; c=~; echo "$c"` -> `/some nonexistent path`

Comment: @user19264607 yes, rbash not needed if we assume `~` is trustworthy: `HOME=$(POSIXLY_CORRECT=1; \unset HOME; \unset -f builtin; builtin printf '%s' ~)`. But perhaps it is enough to just do: `unset HOME; HOME=~` to reset if not trying to protect against a nefarious caller

Answer (score 3):

If "bulletproof" means reliably giving the system's idea of the user's home directory, and does not cover the user attempting to stymie this, then for `bash` you just need to do:

```
unset HOME
HOME=~
```

or

```
unset HOME
export HOME=~
```

This is because, from reading the `bash` source code (in particular, the file `shell.c`), it looks like when `HOME` is unset, the value of `~` is generally taken directly from the `pw_dir` field of the entry returned by calling `getpwuid` on the uid obtained by calling `getuid`.

---

It's probably not possible to fully protect against nefarious actions by the caller of your code.

Comment: This is the best approach, but the current code causes `HOME` to be not exported.  `unset HOME; export HOME=~` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @pjh arguably, if `HOME` is unset when the script runs, it's because the caller wanted it that way, but I guess it's up to the script to decide what to do

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would be reasonable bulletproof

```
HOME=$(/usr/bin/getent passwd $EUID | /usr/bin/cut -d: -f6)
```

#### edit 1

As @Shawn mentioned, we can use `EUID` which is read-only.

#### edit 2

as @Fravadona noticed, `getent` is not available on macOS, then either you can write some small C program or even use python (*python 2.7 which is still the default on macOS mid-2022*)

```
HOME=$(/usr/bin/python -c 'from __future__ import print_function; import os; import pwd; print(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir)')
```

Comment: `command getent passwd $EUID` (EUID is a read-only bash variable)

Comment: @Shawn good point

Comment: `getent` isn't portable; for example it doesn't work on Mac. The only bullet proof way seems to be writting a little C code that calls `getpwuid`

Comment: perhaps interestingly, according to the bash source-code (if I'm reading it correctly), it is actually `UID` that you should be using if you want to match what bash is doing when it sets `~`